# How to combine three variables into one?

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an email form using bootstrap, HTML, and PHP. I have the form here:

```html
<form role="form-horizontal" method="post" action="formsubmit.php" style="width 70%">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to code the PHP so that I receive an email with the responses. I've tried the code below yet when I receive the email its blank.

```html
<?php 
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $comment = $_POST["comment"];
  $message = $name . $email . $comment;
  mail("someone@example.com","New contact form completion", $message )  
?>
```

My goal is to figure out how to get an email with the responses from the form.

Comment: Have you tried to print directly `$message` to see if the problem is at the mail command or in the form submission?

Comment: You should investigate debugging, it will help with this and in the future.

Comment: looks right.. is that your whole formsubmit.php ? add `var_dump($_POST);` to the top of it and see if the array is populated

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>` to `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value='Submit'>` just to make sure.

Comment: The PHP was on the same file as the form, I moved it to formsubmit.php and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$message = print_r($_POST,1);
```